# woocommerce tag a returning customer by billing phone number

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

My checkout is a very simple form i don't register customers and I also don't get emails what I have is only the billing phone number.
so how can I check if the customer is returning using the billing phone number?

no matter how many times a customer orders if the phone number is the same then it should add a tag or column on the order list page in the backend which shows that this order is from the returning customer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the question by myself.
in case someone need help in this here is the code

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 50, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    if ( $column == 'order_number' )
    {
        global $the_order, $wpdb;

        if( $phone = $the_order->get_billing_phone() ){
            $results = $wpdb->get_results('select * from `C2R_postmeta` where meta_key = "_billing_phone" and meta_value = "'.$phone.'"');
            if ( count($results) > 1 ) {
                echo '<span class="return-customer">Returing</span>';
            }
            $phone_wp_dashicon = '<span class="dashicons dashicons-whatsapp"></span> ';
            echo '<a href="https://wa.me/+92'.$phone.'" target="_blank">' . $phone_wp_dashicon . $phone.'</a></strong>';
        }

    }
}
```

and here is the result

[image]

style code here

```
span.return-customer {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ffff58;
    padding: 2px 7px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
}
```